# REST with Spring and Jackson full data binding

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm using Spring MVC to handle JSON POST requests. Underneath the covers I'm using the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter built on the Jackson JSON processor and enabled when you use the mvc:annotation-driven.

One of my services receives a list of actions:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/executeActions", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String executeActions(@RequestBody List<ActionImpl> actions) {
        logger.info("executeActions");
        return "ACK";
    }
```

I have found that Jackson maps the requestBody to a List of java.util.LinkedHashMap items (simple data binding). Instead, I would like the request to be bound to a List of typed objects (in this case "ActionImpl").

I know this is easy to do if you use Jackson's ObjectMapper directly:

```
List<ActionImpl> result = mapper.readValue(src, new TypeReference<List<ActionImpl>>() { });
```

but I was wondering what's the best way to achieve this when using Spring MVC and MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.  Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suspect problem is due to type erasure, i.e. instead of passing generic parameter type, maybe only actions.getClass() is passed; and this would give type equivalent of List< ?>.

If this is true, one possibility would be to use an intermediate sub-class, like:

```
public class ActionImplList extends ArrayList<ActionImpl> { }
```

because this will the retain type information even if only class is passed.
So then:

```
public @ResponseBody String executeActions(@RequestBody ActionImplList actions)
```

would do the trick. Not optimal but should work.

I hope someone with more Spring MVC knowledge can shed light on why parameter type is not being passed (perhaps it's a bug?), but at least there is a work around.

Comment: This problem occurred in Spring 3.1 but was fixed in Spring 3.2: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9570

Answer (score 43):

I have found that you can also work around the type erasure issue by using an array as the @RequestBody instead of a collection.  For example, the following would work:

```
public @ResponseBody String executeActions(@RequestBody ActionImpl[] actions) { //... }
```

Comment: I was stuck on a similar problem, tried this and it works. However by updating to 3.1.1.Release even List<ActionImpl> would work ...

Comment: The behaviour is arbitrary .. still confused

Answer (score 9):

For your information, the feature will be available in Spring 3.2 (see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9570)

I just tested it on current M2 and it works like a charm out of the box (no need to provide additionnal annotation to provide the parameterized type, it will be automatically resolved by new MessageConverter)

Answer (score 2):

This question is already old, but I think I can contribute a bit anyway.

Like StaxMan pointed out, this is due to type erasure. It definitely *should* be possible, because you *can* get the generic arguments via reflection from the method definition. However, the problem is the API of the [HttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html):

```
T read(Class<? extends T> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage);
```

Here, only List.class will be passed to the method. So, as you can see, it is impossible to implement a HttpMessageConverter that calculates the real type by looking at the method parameter type, as that is not available.

Nevertheless, it is possible to code your own workaround - you just won't be using HttpMessageConverter. Spring MVC allows you to write your own [WebArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html) that kicks in before the standard resolution methods. You can for example use your own custom annotation (@JsonRequestBody?) that directly uses an ObjectMapper to parse your value. You will be able to provide the parameter type from the method:

```
final Type parameterType= method.getParameterTypes()[index];
List<ActionImpl> result = mapper.readValue(src, new TypeReference<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return parameterType;
    }
});
```

Not really the way TypeReference was intended to be used I presume, but ObjectMapper doesn't provide a more suitable method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the method as:

```
executeActions(@RequestBody TypeReference<List<ActionImpl>> actions)
```

I haven't tried it, but based on your question it's the first thing I *would* try.

Comment: Nice point, but it doesn't work. Jackson tryes to deserialize the received List as an instance of TypeReference and this produces a JsonMappingException.