# spring controller with deserialized list object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tester/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String  testingonly(@RequestBody List<EachObject> eachobjectlist) throws IOException {
```

then i do iterate eachobjectlist, but each item inside the list is type LinkedHashMap, arent it suppose to be "EachObject" type ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441557/rest-with-spring-and-jackson-full-data-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at runtime, the generic type `EachObject` is not present at runtime. Spring will not be able to determine this information. Spring only knows that the argument has a raw type `List` and it will inject a `List` of any type.</del>

According to @axtavt, generic types of method's arguments are accessible but Spring may not have this implemented and probably won't be implemented in the future. This is because generic type can be interface or abstract class and Spring will not be able to create a corresponding implementation of a given interface or abstract class. For example, if you request for a list of `Fruit` and there are two almost identical subclasses of `Fruit`, dertemining which subclass to be used will not be possible.

Comment: The statement about type erasure is incorrect. `EachObject` can be accessed using `Method.getGenericParameterTypes()`, but perhaps it's not implemented in Spring.