# Map JSON array of objects to @RequestBody List<T> using jackson

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm having issues using Jackson to map a Javascript posted JSON array of hashes (Tag).

Here is the data received by the controller @RequestBody (It is send with correct json requestheader):

```
[{name=tag1}, {name=tag2}, {name=tag3}]
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "purchases/{purchaseId}/tags", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "manyTags")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void createAll(@PathVariable("purchaseId") final Long purchaseId, @RequestBody final List<Tag> entities)
{
        Purchase purchase = purchaseService.getById(purchaseId);

        Set<Tag> tags = purchase.getTags();
        purchaseService.updatePurchase(purchase);
    }
```

When I debug and view the 'entities' value it shows as an ArrayList of generic objects, not as a list of objects of type 'Tag' as I would expect.

How can I get jackson to map a passed array of objects to a list of obejcts of type 'Tag'?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried it like this? `[{"name"="tag1"}, {"name"="tag2"}, {"name"="tag3"}]`

Comment: I haven't tried that Sean, I went with the solution of using an array for the @RequestBody instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441557/rest-with-spring-and-jackson-full-data-binding

Comment: well it works with spring 5.x at least ;)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It sounds like Spring is not passing full type information for some reason, but rather a type-erased version, as if declaration was something like `List<?> tag`. I don't know what can be done to fully resolve this (may need something from Spring integration team), but one work-around is to define your own type like:

```
static class TagList extends ArrayList<Tag> { }
```

and use that instead. This will retain generic parameterization through super-type declarations so that even if Spring only passes equivalent of `TagList.class`, Jackson can figure out the `Tag` parameter.

Comment: Cheers StaxMan....I came across the following link which provies a number of options in addition to your one here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441557/rest-with-spring-and-jackson-full-data-binding

Comment: Thanks StaxMan. I was facing same issue. Your answer helped me.

Comment: That's so simple and practical, I use this in my android app. Thanks

Comment: Does this help deserializing classes that extends Tag as well?

Comment: It helps with generic types; sub-classing is not same as generic types. So you can use same approach to resolve types for generic containers; but this does not automatically mean that polymorphic sub-types are resolved.

Answer (score 20):

Another way to do this is to rather obtain an array than a List, as follows:

```
@RequestBody Tag[] entities
```

Comment: Ok yes Thomas wanted to obtain a List of tags, but seeing that this doesn't work, I have suggested to rather obtain an array. I struggled with this same problem a while back, and at the moment the objects in the List, the generic object, will not be created, maybe this will be fixed in the future, I don't know, so instead of obtaining a List through the RequestBody, one should rather obtain a array of that specific object, without anything having to change on the senders side.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson requires a default constructor with no parameters on custom Objects, so you'll need to simply add a default constructor to your `Tag` class.

In your case simply add to your `Tag` class:

```
public Tag(){}
```