# get pathvariable with sending and recieving json data Rest spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to learn Rest web services using spring mvc. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012841/receiving-json-and-deserializing-as-list-of-object-at-spring-mvc-controller) link.

I am able to receive and send Json data but I am not able to pass pathvariable with the call. I am unable to understand the issue.

Here is my controller:

```
package com.akash.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/myRest")
public class MyRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myAction1/{param1}/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Abc> myAction1(@PathVariable String param1) {

        Abc ob = new Abc();
        ob.setAge(20);
        ob.setName("obama-"+param1);
        List<Abc> listOfAbc = new ArrayList<Abc>();
        listOfAbc.add(ob);
        return listOfAbc;
    }

    /*
     * curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/json"
     * http://localhost:8080/myRest/myAction1/123
     */

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myAction2", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {
            "Accept=application/json", "Content-type=application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody List<Abc> myAction2(@RequestBody AbcWrapper wrapper) {

        Abc ob = new Abc();
        ob.setAge(wrapper.getListOfAbc().size());
        ob.setName("obama");
        List<Abc> listOfAbc = new ArrayList<Abc>();
        listOfAbc.add(ob);
        return listOfAbc;
    }

    /*
     * curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H
     * "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/myRest/myAction2
     * -d "{\"listOfAbc\":[{\"age\":20,\"name\":\"akash\"}]}"
     */
}

class Abc {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class AbcWrapper {
    List<Abc> listOfAbc;

    public List<Abc> getListOfAbc() {
        return listOfAbc;
    }

    public void setListOfAbc(List<Abc> listOfAbc) {
        this.listOfAbc = listOfAbc;
    }
}
```

I am able to execute myAction2 but myAction1 cannot be executed.
If I remove pathvariable from myAction1 everything works fine.

Please help.

Comment: Which HTTP code are you receiving after performing the GET?

Comment: curl -i flag adds the HTTP header in the output.  Nice for debugging.  Only other thing I can think of is trying to add the @PathVariable("param1") String param1.  Not sure if it's required if the variable names matches but that's how I've always seen it used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. There were many mistakes.

(1)The first problem was spring security which was authenticating the url and redirecting it to login page.

I changed this

```
<http pattern="/myRest/*" security="none" />
```

to

```
<http pattern="/myRest/**" security="none" />
```

(2)Changed myAction1 method to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myAction1/{param1}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Abc> myAction1(@PathVariable("param1") String param1, Model model) {
```

removed an extra slash after {param1}

All that information I got from curl -i parameter

Before solving problem

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 05:35:55 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1kk70yuy7kc501glpcd0m9t4py;Path=/
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8080/login;jsessionid=1kk70yuy7kc501glpcd0m9t4py
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.2.3.v20140905)
```

After Solving problem

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 05:37:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.2.3.v20140905)

[{"age":20,"name":"obama-123"}]
```

cheers