# How to receive Json object with audio file and file information in it at the serverside(Spring boot controller)

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, servlets

The JSON object I'm sending something looks like this

```
[
 {'fileName':'nameOftheFile1','file':audio_file1}, 
 {'fileName':'nameOftheFile2','file':audio_file2}
]
```

I tried using Wrapper methods for JSON object but didn't work

This is the link to what I tried
[receiving json and deserializing as List of object at spring mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012841/receiving-json-and-deserializing-as-list-of-object-at-spring-mvc-controller)

Comment: what exactly you can not do?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a MultipartFile for the audios. See the below snippet for an example.

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
     Arrays.stream(files)
           .forEach(file -> {
                //get filename with file.getOriginalFilename()
            });
}
```

Comment: In JSON object there is more than one file.