# Does javax validation work with inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, javax.validation

I am trying to validate a model, which is inheriting from another model and this parent model has **@NotBlank** annotation to validate a parameter. But this validation is bypassed in the controller which is accepting a list of child class objects.

The code snippet should give a fair idea of the scenario

```
public abstract class A {
  @NotBlank
  private String name;
}

public class B extends A {
  private String type;
}

@PostMapping(consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity saveRoles(@Valid @RequestBody List<B> roles){
   // ideally it should not land here if request has blank name. But it seems to land here.
   // logic 
}
```

The request body -

```
[
    {
        "name": "",
        "type": "system"
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes it should and the issue is not related to the annotation not being processed but to how `javax.validation` works. You will need to put `@Valid` on the `<B>` on the list as well. So `List<@Valid B>`. As you are accepting a collection it needs to know it should propagate the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to validate the collection itself, but not the collection elements. Try this:

```
@PostMapping(consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity saveRoles(@RequestBody List<@Valid B> roles){
  
}
```

Comment: Hi @donquih0te
Is this dependent on spring-boot version?
I got this working for 2.2.4 but it did not work for my existing version 2.0.3

Comment: @Chiku Could you go to the `@Valid` annotation source code and check if `ElementType.TYPE_USE` is present inside the `@Target`

Comment: Yes it is present. Since I had time constraints, I got it working by building a wrapper java bean for the list. I referred this link - 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012841/receiving-json-and-deserializing-as-list-of-object-at-spring-mvc-controller/39079259)