# JSON Jackson with Generic Constraint

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, generics, jackson

I'm using JSON Jackson on SpringBoot context. 
I have a problem with Jackson deserialization with Generic type constraint.

This code work fine :

```java
public abstract class AbstractSyncableWriteAndReadResource<T, K> extends AbstractSyncableReadResource<T, K> {

    ...

    @Timed
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<List<SynQueuDTO<T>>> syncPushPut(@RequestBody List<SynQueuDTO<T>> entities) {
        ...
    }

}
```

But this code don't work : 
This code work fine :

```java
public abstract class AbstractSyncableWriteAndReadResource<T extends EntitySyncableWrite, K> extends AbstractSyncableReadResource<T, K> {

    ...

    @Timed
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<List<SynQueuDTO<T>>> syncPushPut(@RequestBody List<SynQueuDTO<T>> entities) {
        ...
    }

}
```

There is only one difference : add Java interface on Generic for constraint Class's type.

Exception :

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class xxx.xxx.xxx.EntitySyncableWrite]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `xxx.xxx.xxx.EntitySyncableWrite` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 26]
```

I try a lot of configurations to force Jackson take Class instead of Interface informations but without success : 
 `@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)`
or `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")` (ko)

Do you have some idea?

Thanks

---

[UPDATE]

An another use case that work very well :

```
public abstract class AbstractSyncableWriteAndReadResource<T extends EntitySyncableWrite, K> ... {

public ResponseEntity<List<SyncQueuDTO<T>>> syncPushPut( @RequestBody SyncQueuDTO<T> data) {
...
}

}
```

But don't work when add RequestBody as List :

```
public abstract class AbstractSyncableWriteAndReadResource<T extends EntitySyncableWrite, K> ... {

public ResponseEntity<List<SyncQueuDTO<T>>> syncPushPut( @RequestBody List<SyncQueuDTO<T>> data) {
...
}

}
```

Exception :

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class xx.xx.xx.EntitySyncableWrite]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `xx.xx.xx.EntitySyncableWrite` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 26] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->xx.xx.xx.SyncQueuDTO[\"serverVersion\"])
```

Comment: see another use case

Answer (score 0):

With [Map JSON array of objects to @RequestBody List<T> using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864049/map-json-array-of-objects-to-requestbody-listt-using-jackson) inspiration I solved this Jackson/JVM limitation as :

```java
public abstract class AbstractSyncableWriteAndReadResource<T extends EntitySyncableWrite, K> extends AbstractSyncableReadResource<T, K> {
  ...

public ResponseEntity<List<SyncQueuDTO<T>>> syncPushPut(@RequestBody SyncQueuDTOList<T> queuList) {
....
}
}
```

and ArrayList implementation :

```java
public class SyncQueuDTOList<T extends EntitySyncableWrite> extends ArrayList<SyncQueuDTO<T>> {}
```