# Spring mvc , Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Vector out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, spring

Ok, im trying to receive this kind of JSON

```
[{"username":"pippo","password":"bla"},{"username":"pluto","password":"bla"},{"username":"topolino","password":"bla"}]
```

But i receive this error:

```
    Resolving exception from handler [public void sequenziatore.server.presenter.LoginController.CheckLogin(java.util.Vector<sequenziatore.server.presenter.Utente>)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Vector out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@68c40ef9; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Vector out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@68c40ef9; line: 1, column: 1]
Resolving exception from handler [public void sequenziatore.server.presenter.LoginController.CheckLogin(java.util.Vector<sequenziatore.server.presenter.Utente>)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Vector out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@68c40ef9; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Vector out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@68c40ef9; line: 1, column: 1]
Resolving exception from handler [public void sequenziatore.server.presenter.LoginController.CheckLogin(java.util.Vector<sequenziatore.server.presenter.Utente>)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Vector out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@68c40ef9; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Vector out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@68c40ef9; line: 1, column: 1]
```

And this is the controller that im using :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public void CheckLogin(@RequestBody Vector<Utente> vec) {
    .....
    }
```

I tried to change the type that i receive with Utente[] instead of Vector but nothing changed, and the real problem is that i don t understand what the error is...
This is the JSON that i receive if i change the receiving type in String and print it...

```
{"0":{"username":"pippo","password":"bla"},"1":{"username":"pluto","password":"bla"},"2":{"username":"topolino","password":"bla"}}
```

This is the class Utente

```
public class Utente {
    private String username=null;
    private String password=null;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Utente(){}
}
```

Comment: The `START_OBJECT` token is simply `{` so it looks like Jackson is trying to read the objects as they were `Vector`s. I'm not sure what the problem is but you could try upgrading to a more recent version https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core

Comment: Done..Nothing changed....

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441557/rest-with-spring-and-jackson-full-data-binding

Comment: @WornOutSoles java.lang.IllegalStateException: No default constructor for [collection type; class sequenziatore.server.presenter.LoginController$UtenteList, contains [simple type, class sequenziatore.server.presenter.Utente]]

Comment: @WornOutSoles public class UtenteList extends ArrayList<Utente> {
  UtenteList(){}
  
 }
As you can see i created the default constructor....

Comment: @DQuaglio have you tried a JSON like this: {"vec":[{"username":"pippo","password":"bla"},{"username":"pluto","password":"bla"},{"username":"topolino","password":"bla"}]}